# Smooth shape shifting animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-canvas, android-custom-view

How to implement smooth shape shifting animation in android ?

I'm rendering polygon shapes on camera preview using `canvas.draw(path, paint)` in `OnDraw()` method of my custom view.

The path is being rendered something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointList.size(); i++) {
        Point currentPoint = adjustedPointList.get(i);

        if (i == 0) {
            //for the first point, we only have to move to that point
            firstPoint = currentPoint;
            mPath.moveTo(currentPoint.getX(), currentPoint.getY());
            //Animation here 

        } else {
            //otherwise we draw a line between last position and current point
            mPath.lineTo(currentPoint.getX(), currentPoint.getY());
            //Animation here

        }
    }


    //we have to draw a last line between last and first point
    if (firstPoint != null) {
        mPath.lineTo(firstPoint.getX(), firstPoint.getY());
        //Animation here
    }
```

I tried the `ObjectAnimator` class like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367950/android-drawing-an-animated-line) but had no effect. Since this is constantly called inside a thread, the shape changes from frame to frame. This is where I want to have a smooth animation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429797/smooth-shape-shift-animation) which is in iOS. How can I do the same for my above illustrated rendering ?

I have also tried solutions for the following questions :

[DashPathEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790936/weird-flickering-with-dashpatheffect-animation)

[path animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674847/how-to-draw-several-lines-slowly-in-constant-velocity-on-canvas-by-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[attach an animator to a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616035/how-to-animate-a-path-on-canvas-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Value Animator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460508/android-move-bitmap-along-a-path/30254774#30254774)

But nothing served my purpose of smooth shape shifting or even animating the drawing of path. currently the shape shift is very flickery.

Also, lot of the shape shifting animation references for android uses bitmaps or SVG which is again not useful for me.

How can I implement this in android ? or is there a different approach to this ? If so, I would like to know everything about it. Thanks!

Comment: see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/34cbdb2/v7/vectordrawable/src/android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/PathParser.java#319 and "animate" the `fraction` from [0..1]

Comment: @pskink How can I use this to morph my path object ?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/29Zqr4

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: @pskink again, I'm not using pathdataNode. The above script is rendering shapes with dynamic points. I do not understand how can I use this in my case. Could you please elaborate ? Thanks again.

Comment: does it work? do you see a blue circle? what do you see if you click on it?

Comment: Wow Amazing, @pskink How you create `PathParser.createNodesFromPathData` with diff values ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya what `"diff values"` you mean?

Comment: means coordinates and all ..

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya sorry i have no idea what you really mean

Comment: Mean How can Get path data for Different shape LIke , 
dest data: `M 16,0 C 16,1 16,15 16,16 15,16 1,16 0,16  0,15  0,1 0,0 1, 0 15, 0 16,0 z`

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya see [9.3. Path data](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData) and [Drawing paths](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html#drawing-paths)

Comment: ok Thanks for help @pskink

Comment: @pskink it works. Thanks. But how do I use it in my case? I'm just using a simple path object.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610321/smooth-shape-shifting-animation#comment92282485_52610321